# Get sinatra environment from within instance method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What's the proper way to determine the environment? Right now I'm using:

```
class Main < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
        puts self.class.development?
        puts self.class.production?
    end
end
```

But it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`self.class.development?` should actually work. These all work for me on Sinatra 1.3.1:

```
class Main < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    puts Main.development?
    puts self.class.development?
    puts settings.development?
    puts settings.environment == :development
  end
end
```

Answer (score 33):

I would use `Sinatra::Base.development?` or `Sinatra::Base.production?` since that is where the methods are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

`puts Sinatra::Application.environment`

`#=> production (or test, development)`